# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout No data showing

Tags: android, android-cardview

It has no error but when I run the holder doesnt show and when I look in to the logcat there has an error RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. Here is my code; I have added layout manager to my recyclerview but it still shows no adapter attached skipping layout.

Here is my fragment class and adapter class code for reference. Please let me know what's the problem.

```
public class dogs extends Fragment 
{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Model> ModelList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dogs, container, false);


        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.Feeddogs);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(),ModelList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);


      showdata();


        return view;
    }

    private void showdata() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Dogs");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ModelList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Model model = snapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    ModelList.add(model);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my adapter code...

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Model> mPost;

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Model> mPost) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Model model = mPost.get(position);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(model.getPetpicture()).into(holder.postimage);
        holder.postname.setText(model.getPetname());
        holder.postbreed.setText(model.getBreed());
        holder.postage.setText(model.getAge());
        holder.postsize.setText(model.getPetsize());
        holder.postcolor.setText(model.getPetcolor());
        holder.postreason.setText(model.getReason());
        ownerinfo( holder.postby,holder.posterimage,model.getUserid());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPost.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CircleImageView posterimage;
        public ImageView postimage;
        public Button like,adoptnme;
        public TextView postby,postname,postbreed,postage,postsize,postcolor,postreason,likecount;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);




            posterimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posterimage);
            postby = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postby);

            postimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postimage);
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            likecount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likecount);
            adoptnme = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adoptme);
            postname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postname);
            postbreed = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postbreed);
            postage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postage);
            postsize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postsize);
            postcolor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postcolor);
            postreason = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postreason);

        }

    }

    private void ownerinfo(final TextView postby, final CircleImageView posterimage, String userid)
    {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UsersHappyPaws usersHappyPaws = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersHappyPaws.class);
                Glide.with(mContext).load(usersHappyPaws.getProfilepic()).into(posterimage);
                postby.setText(usersHappyPaws.getName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on RecyclerView because your data are received asynchronously:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ModelList.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Model model = snapshot.getValue(Model.class);
        ModelList.add(model);
    }
    recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

As for the error, it is only a warning. But if you're concerned about it, you could set the `setAdapter` first before `setLayoutManager`, it must have triggered to dispatch layout update without an adapter, and so that's why you're seeing the warning.